# reverse for ' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls, django-generic-views

I am trying to get a ListView for which `get_absolute_url` is defined in my template. But it raises an error:

> Reverse for 'accept_bid' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'bid_id': 16}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P[\w-]+)/bid/(?P[\w-]+)/$'].

Do I need to define the the two integer id's in my view or is there some other problem?

I would appreciate helping me in solve this.

models.py:

```
class Bid(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name = "bids")
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("accept_bid", kwargs={"bid_id": self.id})
```

Views.py:

```
class LiveBids(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView, FormView ):
    template_name = 'live_bids.html'
    def get_queryset(self):

         return Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('bids').filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('id')
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^live_bids/$', LiveBids.as_view(model=Post), name='LiveBids'),
url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>[\w-]+)/bid/(?P<bid_id>[\w-]+)/$', views.accept_bid, name='accept_bid'),
```

live_bids.html:

```
{% for bid in post.bids.all %}
    {{bid.amount}}
    <p><a href='{{ bid.get_absolute_url }}'>Accept</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include also the value to `post_id`:

```
kwargs={"bid_id": self.id, "post_id": self.post.id}
```

Comment: I get the post_id from the post field(ForeignKey) as defined in my Bid Model. How can define whatever_post_id_is in your answer for getting the post_id??